# How to Have Many datasources in <droppable> Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I want to use more then one datasource in `droppable` but it didn't work with this syntax:

```
<p:droppable id="droptableof" for="lesOf" tolerance="touch" datasource="orderedOf orderedOf2" scope="zone2" activeStyleClass="ui-state-default" hoverStyleClass="ui-state-hover">
    <p:ajax listener="#{beanJsf73.onOfback}" update="order2 lesOf lesOf2"  />
</p:droppable>
```

How we can add two datasources in  in Primefaces ?

Comment: Have you tried multiple `<p:droppable id="droptableof" for="lesOf" datasource="orderedOf"...` and `<p:droppable id="droptableof2" for="lesOf" datasource="orderedOf2"...` ?

Comment: Yes i tryed but this solution didnt work . didnt admit more then one Droppable for same Area .

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't. Check out [Issue 1469](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1469).

The workaround in the discussion might solve your problem